# Need to execute cordoba.exec synchronously in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I'm modifying an app in Ionic and I need to make a function that returns the remaining storage space in the device. Problem I've is that cordoba.exec executes asynchronous and returns the value after the function that contains it already returned the value. How can I make the process to wait for the result.

```
var getFreeSpace = function() {
    var value = -1;

    cordova.exec(function(result) {
        value = result;
        console.log("Free Disk Space: " + result);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("Error getFreeDiskSpace: " + e.error);
    }, "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []);

    return value;
}

console.log('getFreeSpace',getFreeSpace());
```

This consoles like this:

```
getFreeSpace -1
Free Disk Space: 500000
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try out this.

```
var getFreeSpace = function() {
    var value = -1;

    cordova.exec(function(result) {
        value = result;
        console.log("Free Disk Space: " + result);
        setTimeout(getFreeSpace, 0)// this will call after you get the result only.You can set delay if u want.
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("Error getFreeDiskSpace: " + e.error);
    }, "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []);

    return value;
}

console.log('getFreeSpace',getFreeSpace());
```